# Object has no attribute issue

Tags: python, django, attributes

I've followed a tutorial on how to create a CRM via Python, Django and came across an issue in the end result.

When I attempt to convert a lead into a client, I am faced with 'Lead' object has no attribute 'comment'.  This is present if the lead has comments under it and if it does not.

But once I get back to the lead list, I notice that the lead has been converted and duplicate 4 times. Has anyone else come across this issue? And how would I go about fixing it?

Below is the models.py file

```
class Lead(models.Model):
    LOW = "low"
    MEDIUM = "medium"
    HIGH = "high"

    CHOICES_PRIORITY = ((LOW, "Low"), (MEDIUM, "Medium"), (HIGH, "High"))

    team = models.ForeignKey(Team, related_name="leads", on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    email = models.EmailField()
    number = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    description = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    priority = models.CharField(max_length=10, choices=CHOICES_PRIORITY, default=MEDIUM)
    converted_to_client = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    created_by = models.ForeignKey(
        User, related_name="leads", on_delete=models.CASCADE, default="Admin"
    )
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    modified_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ("name",)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class Comment(models.Model):
    team = models.ForeignKey(
        Team, related_name="lead_comments", on_delete=models.CASCADE
    )
    lead = models.ForeignKey(Lead, related_name="comments", on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    content = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    created_by = models.ForeignKey(
        User, related_name="lead_comments", on_delete=models.CASCADE
    )
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.created_by.username
```

This is the error shown:

'Lead' object has no attribute 'comment'
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/dashboard/leads/17/convert/
Django Version: 4.2.1
Exception Type: AttributeError
Exception Value:
'Lead' object has no attribute 'comment'

Below is the views.py file:

```
class ConvertToClientView(LoginRequiredMixin, View):
    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        pk = self.kwargs.get("pk")

        lead = get_object_or_404(Lead, created_by=request.user, pk=pk)
        team = self.request.user.userprofile.active_team

        client = Client.objects.create(
            name=lead.name,
            email=lead.email,
            number=lead.number,
            description=lead.description,
            created_by=request.user,
            team=team,
        )

        lead.converted_to_client = True
        lead.save()

        # Convert Comments from Lead to Client Comments

        comments = lead.comment.all()

        for comment in comments:
            ClientComment.objects.create(
                client=client,
                content=comment.content,
                created_by=comment.created_by,
                team=team,
            )

        messages.success(request, "The lead was converted")

        return redirect("leads:list")
```

I've attempted to place an if statement prior to the for loop, however it did not resolve the matter.

I'm hoping to get rid of the attribute error, and prevent the action from duplicating the objects.

Comment: Always give the full traceback please, it's hard to follow unfamiliar code when there is no indication where is the problem

Comment: Sorry, I thought the rest was gibberish, so did not include, I'll keep it in mind!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `related_name` of Comment to Lead relation is `comments`

```py
lead = models.ForeignKey(Lead, related_name="comments", on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

but you refer it as `comment`

```py
comments = lead.comment.all()
```

So it's just a typo

Comment: Thank you so much! I've pulled an all nighter writing all this, so eyes are a bit blurry right now! You're a life saver!

Comment: I'm not sure what causes duplication, first I'd change the code to run on POST, because it's alters data making it formally more correct then, check existance of the Client and then wrap whole creation operation into an atomic transaction: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/topics/db/transactions/
It should help prevent some undesired cases.